# String formatting of data in column of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I remove `'$'` in a column values?
**Example**: I have a column with values like `$40`, `$23`, `$35`,
I want to see those column values like `40`, `23`, `35`.

I have already tried:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].replace(r'$', '')
```

This didn't work!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "This didnt work!" does not help us understand the problem. Please explain exactly what did happen, what was supposed to happen instead, and how that is different.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I think we can assume that the `$`s weren't removed…although something definitive would be nice.

Answer (score 3):

[`Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html#pandas.Series.replace) replaces all values in the column that *exactly match* the first argument.  You want [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace) to replace a substring:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].str.replace(r'$', '')
```

Comment: This is a superior solution to the unvectorized one I posted a minute ago.

Comment: @AllDownhillFromHere For the record, this solution is not "vectorized"; it is Cython-level for loops. In fact, your now-deleted solution turned out to be faster for a 30,000-record series  in my test. 10.4 vs 7.77 ms.

Comment: Guess I shouldn't have been so fast deleting it, then (*presses undelete*)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all elements in you vector:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = [x.replace(r'$', '') for x in DF_['H1 % Change'] ]
```

This will replace elements one-by-one

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it with [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with supplying the parameter `regex=`, as follows:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].replace(r'\$', '', regex=True)
```

#### Demo

**Data Input**

```
DF_ = pd.DataFrame({'H1 % Change': ['$40', '$23', '$35']})

print(DF_)

  H1 % Change
0         $40
1         $23
2         $35
```

**Output**

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].replace(r'\$', '', regex=True)

print(DF_)

  H1 % Change
0          40
1          23
2          35
```

Here, with specifying `regex=True`, the first parameter is regarded as a regex.  Hence, we need to quote the regex as `\$` (with a backslash) in order to "escape" the `$` symbol which, by coincident, is also a regex metacharacter (for end-of string anchor).

#### Detailed Explanation

Some more background information below for your reference:

Your code with [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) doesn't work because by default, `regex=False` for [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) and with this setting, you can see from the [official document](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) (extracted below):

> Parameters **to_replace**    str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or
> None

> **str**: string **exactly matching** to_replace will be replaced with value
>
> **regex**: regexs matching to_replace will be replaced with value

that when we supply the first parameter `to_replace` with a string (with default `regex=False`), it requires **exact matching** (full-match) string in order to replace.  That is, if you specify `$`, then no other characters are allowed in the testing string, in order to get a match.

When it is a regex (with `regex=True`), testing string matching the regex (can be partial match) will be regarded as a match.

#### Alternate Solution

Another way to remove the dollar sign `$` is by using [`.str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), which has by default `regex=True`.  Hence, we can do it simply by:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].str.replace(r'\$', '')
```

or simply:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].str.replace(r'$', '')
```

Here, it turns out that we can use both `\$` (with backslash) and `$` (without backslash) to achieve the same result.

For people using newer version of Pandas, you may get a warning message if you don't specify the parameter `regex=`:

`FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version.`

Hence, it is recommended to quote also the parameter `regex=` as well, like below:

```
DF_['H1 % Change'] = DF_['H1 % Change'].str.replace(r'\$', '', regex=True)
```